# Workspace-switching problem

Tags: unity, compiz, workspaces, workspace-switcher

Press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. You should see your 4 workspaces. Move your mouse, go over another workspace other than that which you were in. Press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> again. You should go to the workspace that **had the mouse over it** not back to the one where you started.

I can't do that anymore. It goes back to the first workspace. How can I correct this?

Comment: I have the same "issue". As far as I'm concerned we click nowadays. I'm not certain, but I think your problem is very difficult to solve.

Comment: yes I replace it by clicking now :( ...I'll just keep waiting.

Comment: Curiously, if you already have the hand on the mouse, there's not much point in pressing Super+S. If you have both hands on the keyboard, this behavior makes sense (but then you can Super+S -> Move with arrows -> Enter or Space, I think).

Comment: yes yes there are many ways I can replace this move but the thing is; I really like this move, it's the easiest and fastest for me to use. ...I think I mostly have my left hand at the keyboard and the other on the mouse. maybe that's why I like this move.

Comment: @MinaMichael, so even Super+s scroll Super+s does not replace what you need.

Comment: nope. ...hint; my method used to take less than 0.5 seconds, scrolling takes more than 3. That's what I can say

Answer (score 0):

Best way to switch workspaces is

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>

and

if you want to switch an opened application to other workspaces:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>

Comment: yeah well that's the normal method. I'm explaining **another** method I've been using and I can't use anymore and that I want back. (dunno why it's gone, maybe it was because of an update). thanks anyway :)