# How do I reset expo?

Tags: workspace-switcher

Expo is that which you see when you press <kbd>super</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. I'm having trouble with it. I explained it all [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492219/workspace-switching-problem). I want to fix it. How do I "reset it" to its defaults or how do I uninstall (or purge) it and reinstall it? What packages does it use?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Compiz Config Setting Manager (`ccsm`):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Open it, in Desktop select Expo
3. On first tab pass by clicks on reset buttons on right edge. Do same thing on remaining tabs.

[image: compiz plugin reset]

Comment: hmmm well okay that answer would work for others but sadly it didn't work for me.